# upserting a task using database.upsert

Tags: apex, tasks, upsert

I am actually upserting a task using the Database.upsert method, but getting the following errors when compilling :

> Upsert require a concrete SObject type.

my code is as follow :

```
 list<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.upsert(sList,Task.Fields.RestoreID__c,false);
```

In the documentation the second parameter seems correct as they give this example : `Schema.SObjectField f = Account.Fields.MyExternalId`

I created an external id field on activity to be used for upsert, and salesforce allowed me. In my schema, i can see the field. But when i am trying to reference this field in my code, its blocking me.

Does anyone know the reason and how can i resolve this ?

Comment: can u post ur complete code ? what's sList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an undocumented limitation of the [upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_upsert_2) API where the first argument must be a list of a specific type e.g.:

```
Tasks[] sList = ...
```

rather than the base SObject type:

```
SObject[] sList = ...
```

for the call to work.

Comment: yes it was this. Because my sList is a list of sObject.